# UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES error while trying to create jar

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark

I'm trying to build a Scala jar file to run it in spark.
I'm following this [tutorial](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html).
when trying to build jar file using sbt as [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start.html#standalone-applications), i'm facing with following error

```
[info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10.4;1.0.2 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10.4;1.0.2
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /home/hduser/.ivy2/local/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.10.4/1.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Akka Repository: tried
[warn]   http://repo.akka.io/releases/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10.4/1.0.2/spark-core_2.10.4-1.0.2.pom
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.10.4/1.0.2/spark-core_2.10.4-1.0.2.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10.4;1.0.2: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/home/prithvi/scala/asd/}default-d57abf/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10.4;1.0.2: not found
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed 13 Aug, 2014 5:24:24 PM
```

what's the issue and how to solve it.

---

Dependency issue has been resolved. Thank you "om-nom-nom"
but new error arised

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.transaction;1.1.1.v201105210645!javax.transaction.orbit
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.mail.glassfish;1.4.1.v201005082020!javax.mail.glassfish.orbit
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.activation;1.1.0.v201105071233!javax.activation.orbit
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/home/prithvi/scala/asd/}default-c011e4/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.transaction;1.1.1.v201105210645!javax.transaction.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.mail.glassfish;1.4.1.v201005082020!javax.mail.glassfish.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.activation;1.1.0.v201105071233!javax.activation.orbit
[error] Total time: 855 s, completed 14 Aug, 2014 12:28:33 PM
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You have your dependency defined as

```
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.0.2"
```

That `%%` instructs sbt to substitute current scala version to artifact name. Apparently, [spark was build for the whole family of 2.10](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/) scala, without specific jars for 2.10.1, 2.10.2 ...

So all you have to do is to redefine it as:

```
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.0.2"
```

Comment: I changed my dependency as `"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core_2.10" % "1.0.1"` and issue is not solved. It's still searching for __spark-core_2.10.4;1.0.2__ and it's showing `[warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.10.4;1.0.2`

Comment: @Y.Prithvi you have to use single ℅, not double. Consider second snippet!

Comment: That issue is resolved could you suggest anything for this new error(edited in question)

Comment: @Y.Prithvi I guess you would be better to ask yet another question, with your sbt file attached.

Comment: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25306976/failed-download-error-while-trying-to-create-scala-jar)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.
Looks like that some bugs are in different versions/compilations/etc.

For me the following build.sbt worked fine

```
name := "My Project"  
version := "1.0"  
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"  
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.2"
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

spark-core_2.10.4;1.0.2 means that it is build on top of scala 2.10 vesion. 
so you have to specified this scalaVersion  := "2.10.4" in your build file. 
Please check your .sbt file and change accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
"org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.1.0",
"org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016",
"org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.transaction" % "1.1.1.v201105210645",
"org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.mail.glassfish" % "1.4.1.v201005082020"
```

)

Answer (score 0):

How can you change the current dependencies? I mean, when you type sbt package for a build file like:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"
```

SBT will start resolving and downloading all kinds of dependencies. But if you see that it is failing on a dependency that is no longer inthe maven repo, what to do? Where can you change the dpencies it tries.

@OP: The problem is that your SBT is outdated. If you downloaded it using apt, you can use apt to remove it as well. In any case, download the latest .tgz (not the .deb) and simply unpack it, after that add the /sbt/bin/ folder to your .bashrc I noticed that older SBT's  (the .deb and apt-get versions) work with older scala versions. You either need to manually add or change the dependencies that the older SBT is trying to find or simply change to the latest (not sooo)SBT.