# FAILED DOWNLOAD error while trying to create scala jar

Tags: scala, sbt, apache-spark

I'm trying to build a Scala jar file to run it in spark.
I'm following this tutorial
when trying to build jar file using sbt as here, i'm facing with following error

```
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.transaction;1.1.1.v201105210645!javax.transaction.orbit
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.mail.glassfish;1.4.1.v201005082020!javax.mail.glassfish.orbit
[warn]  :: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.activation;1.1.0.v201105071233!javax.activation.orbit
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[error] {file:/home/prithvi/scala/asd/}default-c011e4/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.transaction;1.1.1.v201105210645!javax.transaction.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.mail.glassfish;1.4.1.v201005082020!javax.mail.glassfish.orbit
[error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.activation;1.1.0.v201105071233!javax.activation.orbit
[error] Total time: 855 s, completed 14 Aug, 2014 12:28:33 PM
```

My .sbt file:

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.3"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.0.2"

resolvers += "Akka Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/releases/"
```

Comment: Those artifacts are presented in maven central. I tried to re-create your project from scratch and updates went effortlessly. That means that problems are likely coupled with your environment. Can you copy resolution details? Can you [open this link in your browser](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/orbit/javax.servlet/3.0.0.v201112011016/) (given that you develop locally)? If yes, can you  drop ivy caches? (usually, they're in `~/.ivy2/cache/`)

Comment: I modified my sbt file [like shown here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PU0Wq6LPrlhOt8-zcTM2ZlBzIfIjB8NVn8aL-F2Y_wA/edit?usp=sharing). I don't know what's going on but I think those files are being skipped.

Comment: can you tell me what's going on in that sbt file and is it correct to proceed this way? I followed [this link](https://github.com/amplab/MLI/issues/4)

Comment: apparently, I didn't got the same problem because my sbt has `0.13.5` version. Don't you want to upgrade to a newer build?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" artifacts (
    Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")
  )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

After this error, I tried installing JAVA 8 and then, it worked for me:

```
   $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java

   $ sudo apt-get update

   $ sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```