# sbt got error when run Spark hello world code?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt

I got the following error when running a spark hello world program.

```
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/sqlServer/}sqlserver...
[info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.1.1 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.1.1
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\user1\.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.12\2.1.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.12/2.1.1/spark-core_2.12-2.1.1.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\user1\.sbt\preloaded\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.12\2.1.1\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/user1/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.12/2.1.1/spark-core_2.12-2.1.1.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.14.3 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.1.1: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.12:2.1.1 (C:\Users\user1\IdeaProjects\sqlServer\build.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]            +- mpa:mpa_2.12:1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.12;2.1.1: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed May 9, 2017 11:05:44 AM
```

Here is the **build.sbt**,

```
name := "Mpa"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.1"
```

My Spark webcome message.

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_111)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

**Update:**

I changed the `built.sbt` to

```
name := "Mpa"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

But still got

```
[info] Updating {file:/C:/Users/user1/IdeaProjects/sqlServer/}sqlserver...
[info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11_2.11;2.1.0 ...
[warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11_2.11;2.1.0
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\user1\.ivy2\local\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.11_2.11\2.1.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11_2.11/2.1.0/spark-core_2.11_2.11-2.1.0.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   C:\Users\user1\.sbt\preloaded\org.apache.spark\spark-core_2.11_2.11\2.1.0\ivys\ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:/C:/Users/user1/.sbt/preloaded/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11_2.11/2.1.0/spark-core_2.11_2.11-2.1.0.pom
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11_2.11;2.1.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11_2.11:2.1.0 (C:\Users\user1\IdeaProjects\sqlServer\build.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]            +- mpa:mpa_2.11:1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11_2.11;2.1.0: not found
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed May 9, 2017 1:01:01 PM
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES error while trying to create jar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285855/unresolved-dependencies-error-while-trying-to-create-jar)

Comment: @Harald I used the answer in the question in your comment and it's still not working. The answer was posted three years ago.

Comment: I ran into this same problem now 4 years later. It is important to use the correct spark-core version for your scala version. A table of suitable versions can be found here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Your have an error in built.sbt file, you must change `%%` to `%`:

```
name := "Mpa"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core" % "2.1.1"
```

`%%` asks Sbt to add the current scala version to the artifact

You can `spark-core_2.11` with `%` to get the issue solved.

```
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I changed the last line in `built.sbt` and still get error `[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]          org.apache.spark:spark-core_2.11_2.11:2.1.0 (C:\Users\WangYi\IdeaProjects\sqlServer\build.sbt#L7-8)
[warn]            +- mpa:mpa_2.11:1.0
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last *:update for the full output.
[error] (*:update) sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11_2.11;2.1.0: not found
[error] Total time: 22 s, completed May 9, 2017 12:55:35 PM1

Comment: 1) Check carefully the number of `%` signs. If you specify scala version in the dependency explicitly use single `%` :  `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"` . Or you can use `%%` notation to use version from `scalaVersion` property: `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.1.0"` . Seems that you mixed things up.

Comment: 2) also sbt picks scala 2.12 version from somewhere. Delete all mentions of `2.12` from the build file.

Comment: @simpadjo Changing `%%` to `%` works. Not exactly about (2) in your comments. I didn't specify `2.12` in my build.sbt?

Comment: i think the "spark-core_2.11" part is the most important. I literally missed this and spend considerable amount of time on this issue.

Answer (score 8):

I got the same error.

build.sbt

```
name := "Simple Project"  
version := "1.0"  
scalaVersion := "2.12.3"  
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
```

just change scalaVersion to 2.11.8 or lower. And it works.

Comment: This works for me. I used 'scalaVersion' 2.13.2 at first. But it kept telling me Not Found Error. I am using 2.11.8 now. Everything goes well.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error and resolved it by below steps. Basically, the filename did not match the sbt configuration.
- Check filename of the spark core jar in $SPARK_HOME/jars ( it is spark-core_**2.11**-2.1.1.jar).
- Install scala **2.11**.11.
- Edit build.sbt to *scalaVersion := "**2.11**.11"*.

Comment: that is exactly what you need to do, e.g. if your spark is 2.2.0 most likely you will have  spark-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar   so you're looking at 2.11.x scala, the following sbt build will work for you assuming you have 2.2 spark:                                                         
 scalaVersion := "2.11.12"


libraryDependencies ++= {
  val sparkVer = "2.2.0"
  Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % sparkVer
  )
}

Answer (score 1):

Versioning Pair that works for 2.11.12.

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.3.2",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.3.2"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Sample build.sbt

```
name := "testproj"

version := "0.1"

scalaVersion := "2.11.9"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

**SparkSession** is available in *spark-sql* library.
You must've to add *spark-sql* dependency to the build.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.2.1"
```